# How do I add a peek function to my heap Class?

Tags: c++, debugging, c++11, data-structures, heap

I made some changes to the previous code in Heap.h and cpp file, as well in the PQ.. and added a PQ.cpp. I am trying to create a heap ADT that will become an Heap implementation of a priority queue. I am just trying to add a peek function to the heap declaration, but I cannot without receiving errors.
Which include these errors.

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "PrecondViolatedExcep::PrecondViolatedExcep(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator > const&)", referenced from:
      pqClass::peek() const in PQ.o
      heapClass::peekTop() const in Heap.o
  "itemClass::GetDirection() const", referenced from:
      enqRequest(int, int, int, bool, itemClass&, pqClass, pqClass) in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Heap.h

```
// *********************************************************
// Header file Heap.h for the ADT heap.
// *********************************************************

#include "Data.h"  // definition of itemClass

#pragma once

const int MAX_HEAP = 20;
typedef itemClass keyType;

typedef itemClass heapItemType;

class heapClass
{
public:
heapClass();  // default constructor
// copy constructor and destructor are
// supplied by the compiler

// heap operations:
virtual bool HeapIsEmpty() const;
// Determines whether a heap is empty.
// Precondition: None.
// Postcondition: Returns true if the heap is empty;
// otherwise returns false.

virtual void HeapInsert(const heapItemType& NewItem,
                        bool& Success);
// Inserts an item into a heap.
// Precondition: NewItem is the item to be inserted.
// Postcondition: If the heap was not full, NewItem is
// in its proper position and Success is true;
// otherwise Success is false.

virtual void HeapDelete(heapItemType& RootItem,
                        bool& Success);
// Retrieves and deletes the item in the root of a heap.
// This item has the largest search key in the heap.
// Precondition: None.
// Postcondition: If the heap was not empty, RootItem
// is the retrieved item, the item is deleted from the
// heap, and Success is true. However, if the heap was
// empty, removal is impossible and Success is false.

heapItemType peekTop() const throw(PrecondViolatedExcep);
protected:
void RebuildHeap(int Root);
// Converts the semiheap rooted at index Root
// into a heap.

private:
heapItemType Items[MAX_HEAP];  // array of heap items
int          Size;             // number of heap items
};  // end class
// End of header file.
```

Heap.cpp

```
// *********************************************************
// Implementation file Heap.cpp for the ADT heap.
// *********************************************************
#include "Heap.h"  // header file for heap

heapClass::heapClass() : Size(0)
{
}  // end default constructor

bool heapClass::HeapIsEmpty() const
{
return bool(Size == 0);
}  // end HeapIsEmpty

void heapClass::HeapInsert(const heapItemType& NewItem,
                       bool& Success)
// Method: Inserts the new item after the last item in the
// heap and trickles it up to its proper position. The
// heap is full when it contains MAX_HEAP items.
{
Success = bool(Size < MAX_HEAP);

if (Success)
{  // place the new item at the end of the heap
    Items[Size] = NewItem;

    // trickle new item up to its proper position
    int Place = Size;
    int Parent = (Place - 1)/2;
    while ( (Parent >= 0) &&
           (Items[Place].Key() > Items[Parent].Key()) )
    {  // swap Items[Place] and Items[Parent]
        heapItemType Temp = Items[Parent];
        Items[Parent] = Items[Place];
        Items[Place] = Temp;

        Place = Parent;
        Parent = (Place -1 )/2;
    }  // end while

    ++Size;
}  // end if
}  // end HeapInsert

void heapClass::HeapDelete(heapItemType& RootItem,
                       bool& Success)
// Method: Swaps the last item in the heap with the root
// and trickles it down to its proper position.
{
Success = bool(!HeapIsEmpty());

if (Success)
{  RootItem = Items[0];
    Items[0] = Items[--Size];
    RebuildHeap(0);
}  // end if
}  // end HeapDelete

void heapClass::RebuildHeap(int Root)
{
// if the root is not a leaf and the root's search key
// is less than the larger of the search keys in the
// root's children
int Child = 2 * Root + 1;  // index of root's left
// child, if any
if ( Child < Size )
{  // root is not a leaf, so it has a left child at Child
    int RightChild = Child + 1;  // index of right child,
    // if any

    // if root has a right child, find larger child
    if ( (RightChild < Size) &&
        (Items[RightChild].Key() > Items[Child].Key()) )
        Child = RightChild;  // index of larger child

    // if the root's value is smaller than the
    // value in the larger child, swap values
    if ( Items[Root].Key() < Items[Child].Key() )
    {  heapItemType Temp = Items[Root];
        Items[Root] = Items[Child];
        Items[Child] = Temp;

        // transform the new subtree into a heap
        RebuildHeap(Child);
    }  // end if
    }  // end if

   // if root is a leaf, do nothing
}  // end RebuildHeap

 heapItemType heapClass::peekTop() const throw(PrecondViolatedExcep)
{
    if (HeapIsEmpty())
    throw PrecondViolatedExcep("Attempted peek into an empty heap.");

    return Items[0];
 } // end peekTop
```

Priority queue 
PQ.h

```
   // *********************************************************
  // Header file PQ.h for the ADT priority queue.
 // Heap implementation.
// *********************************************************
#include "Heap.h"  // ADT heap operations

typedef heapItemType pqItemType;

class pqClass
   {
  public:
    // default constructor, copy constructor, and
   // destructor are supplied by the compiler

// priority-queue operations:
virtual bool PQueueIsEmpty() const;
virtual void PQueueInsert(const pqItemType& NewItem,
                          bool& Success);
virtual void PQueueDelete(pqItemType& PriorityItem,
                          bool& Success);

pqItemType peek() const throw(PrecondViolatedExcep);

private:
heapClass H;
};  // end class
// End of header file.
```

PQ.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
// *********************************************************
// Implementation file PQ.cpp for the ADT priority queue.
// A heap represents the priority queue.
// *********************************************************
#include "PQ.h"    // header file for priority queue

bool pqClass::PQueueIsEmpty() const
{
    return H.HeapIsEmpty();
}  // end PQueueIsEmpty

 void pqClass::PQueueInsert(const pqItemType& NewItem,
                       bool& Success)
{
   H.HeapInsert(NewItem, Success);
}  // end PQueueInsert

void pqClass::PQueueDelete(pqItemType& PriorityItem,
                       bool& Success)
{
   H.HeapDelete(PriorityItem, Success);
}  // end PQueueDelete

 pqItemType pqClass::peek() const throw(PrecondViolatedExcep) {
   try
 {
    return H.peekTop();
 }
   catch (PrecondViolatedExcep e) {
       throw PrecondViolatedExcep("Attempted peek into an empty   priority       queue."); } // end try/catch
} // end peek
// End of implementation file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add a `const` to your function signature in the .cpp file so it matches the signature in your .h file.

Comment: Also, see the other answer on how to improve your function implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an object of abstruct class in PQ.h:

```
heapClass H;
```

also you trying to access an element only if the heap IS empty

```
heapItemType heapClass::peekTop(){
  if (HeapIsEmpty())

  return heapItemType[0];
}
```

you need something like this (in case if your type is a pointer):

```
heapItemType heapClass::peekTop(){
  if (HeapIsEmpty()) {
    return nullptr;
  }

  return heapItemType[0];
}
```

or you need some kind of invalid object you can return in case of empty heap

Comment: He will have to change the function definition to const also to get rid of the compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell by looking at your code you have defined your method of your `heapClass` as such:

```
virtual heapItemType peekTop() const =0;
```

This is being declared as a pure virtual function since you are setting it equal to 0 in its declaration within the class. This will cause your `heapClass` to be abstract. All that I see from within your `pqClass` is that you are storing an object of type `heapClass`. I do not see any inheritance here and this is one of the reasons why you may be getting build or compiler errors. You can not declare a method or function within a class to be purely virtual without inheriting from it. I don't know if this is what you intended or not. But as it stands right now your `heapClass` is abstract with this type of method declaration!

You would either need to remove the `= 0` from its declaration or inherit from this class where the derived class will implement this function with the `override` directive. Also Anon Mail is correct you will also need to declare the method as being `const` in your implementation file, and Andrew Lavq has a valid point about the actual implementation of your function.